# SQL Select Statement Queries

Tags: sql-server, select, join, sql

These are the created tables I am working with:

```
create table Customer2 (cid char(3), cname char(10), primary key (Cid)); 

create table Employee2 
(
     eid char(3), ename char(10), salary number(7,2), 
     mid char(3), 
     primary key (eid), foreign key (mid) references Employee2
); 

create table ArtObject2 
(
      aoid char(3), atitle char(12), artist varchar(10), pricea number(8,2), 
      primary key (aoid)
); 

create table MakesD2 
(
     aoid char(3), eid char(3), cid char(3), prices number, dates date, 
     primary key (aoid, CID), 
     foreign key (aoid) references ArtObject2, 
     foreign key (CID) references Customer2, 
     foreign key (eid) references Employee2
);
```

I need to write the following SQL statements:

1. find the names of customers who bought the highest number of paintings.
2. Find the customers who bought more than one painting after 1-JUL-12
3. For each painting sold display title of the painting, the price paid by a customer 
   and the words "Higher than average" if the painting was sold on the price grater than average asking price and the words "Lower than average" if the painting was sold on the 
   price less than average asking price. For the column holding the words "Higher than 
   asking" or "Lower than asking" make a header Remark.

I tried this statement for #1 but did not work:

```
select cname 
from customer2 
where cid in 
      (select cid 
       from makesd2 
       where prices >=ALL(select prices from makesd2 group by cname)
      );
```

I tried this statement for #2 but did not return all results:

```
select cname 
from customer2 
where cid in
      (select cid 
       from makesd2 
       where dates > '1-JUL-12' 
       group by cid 
       having count(cid) > 1);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is this for your homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: You have to make a subquery to get the number of paintings bought by each customer and JOIN with customer2 table to get the customer's name:

```
SELECT c.cname
FROM Customer2 c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT cid,
    COUNT(*) AS bought
  FROM makesd2
  GROUP BY cid
  ) m ON m.cid = c.cid
ORDER BY m.bought
```

2: Same as above, but in this one, you find what are the cid's that bought more than one painting since that date:

```
SELECT c.cname
FROM Customer2 c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT cid,
    COUNT(*) AS bought
  FROM makesd2
  WHERE dates > '1-JUL-12'
  GROUP BY cid
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) m ON m.cid = c.cid
```

3: This one is a simple use of CASE:

```
SELECT a.atitle,
  m.prices,
  CASE 
    WHEN m.aprice > (SELECT AVG(prices) FROM MakesD2)
      THEN 'Higher than average'
    ELSE 'Lower than average'
  END AS averageRating
FROM MakesD2 m
INNER JOIN ArtObject2 a ON a.aoid = m.aoid
```